# Spyder 5.4.3 installed via Anaconda Navigator - You have missing dependencies! pylsp >=1.7.2,<1.8.0 : 1.7.1 (NOK)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've been using Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda Navigator on Mac OS for 6 months with no issues. Today I went to try Spyder for the first time and I'm getting this message:

*You have missing dependencies!
Mandatory:
pylsp >=1.7.2,<1.8.0 : 1.7.1 (NOK)
Please install them to avoid this message.
Note: Spyder could work without some of these dependencies, however to have a smooth experience when using Spyder we strongly recommend you to install all the listed missing dependencies.
Failing to install these dependencies might result in bugs. Please be sure that any found bugs are not the direct result of missing dependencies, prior to reporting a new issue.*

I've updated to the latest version of Anaconda, I've de-installed and re-installed Spyder a couple of times - no change.

I have also tried updating pylsp via the Mac OS Terminal with `conda install pylsp` and `conda update pylsp` but I'm getting `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`

Seems like variations of this issue have been coming up for years - lots of similar questions here on SO.

I'm not experienced enough to take this any further myself - can anyone help me fix it?

/ Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. It took me a while to figure out what was going on, but the problem is the python-lsp-server package, which is inconveniently shortened to "pylsp" in the warning box. Open up an Anaconda prompt as an administrator. If you run `conda list` , you'll see a list of all packages installed for your python build. Scroll up the alphabetical list to find python-lsp-server, and verify that the version is, indeed, less than 1.7.2. If so, the following worked for me to update it.

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-lsp-server=1.7.2
```

Comment: Running `conda list` showed I didn't have any `python-lsp-xxx` packages installed at all. Your answer looks like its resolved the issue and Spyder now starts without any warnings. Thanks!